# Simulating a combination of PDEs and ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, control-systems

I am trying to simulate a combination of PDEs and ODEs, given below.

$$ \begin{matrix}
     -L\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}I(t,z)&=&\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}V(t,z)+RI(t,z)\\
     C\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}V(t,z)&=& -GV(t,z)-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}I(t,z)
     \end{matrix}\hspace{8mm}0<z<1
    $$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
     -L_0\dfrac{d}{d t}I(t,0)&=&R_0I(t,0)+V(t,0)-E_0(t)\\
    \dfrac{d}{dt}E_0(t)&=&-K_p\left(I(t,0)-I_d\right)-K_d \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}I(t,0)
    \end{matrix}~\;\;\;z=0\\
    $$

$$
     \begin{matrix}
    -L_1\dfrac{d}{d t}I(t,1)&=& R_1I(t,1)-V(t,1)+v(t)\\
    C_1\dfrac{d}{dt}v(t)&=& I(t,1)-\dfrac{v(t)}{R_C}
     \end{matrix}~\;\;\;\;z=1
    $$

All constants can be taken as `1`.

PS: I have tried the following:

```
l = 1; l0 = 1; l1 = 1; c = 1; c1 = 1;
r = 1; g = 1; r0 = 1; r1 = 1; rc = 1;
Ki = 1;
Kd = 2;
Ib0d = 5;
simtime = 10;
var = {Is[t, x], Vs[t, x], Ib0[t], Ib1[t], Vb1[t], Eb0[t]} // Flatten
varInit = var /. {t -> 0};
pde = Inverse[
    DiagonalMatrix[{-l, c}]].{D[Vs[t, x], x] + 
     r*Is[t, x], -g*Vs[t, x] - D[Is[t, x], x]};
MatrixForm[pde];
ode = Inverse[
    DiagonalMatrix[{-l0, -l1, c1}]].{r0*Ib0[t] + Vs[t, 0] - Eb0[t], 
    r1*Ib1[t] + Vb1[t] - Vs[t, 1], Ib1[t] - Vb1[t]/rc};
MatrixForm[ode];
uode = {-Ki*(Ib0[t] - Ib0d) - Kd*(r0*Ib0[t] + Vs[t, 0] - Eb0[t])/-l0};
MatrixForm[uode];
f = {pde, ode, uode} // Flatten;
DAE = {Thread[D[var, t] == f], Ib0[t] == Is[t, 0], Ib1[t] == Is[t, 1],
    Thread[ varInit == Flatten[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 6}]]]} // 
  Flatten; MatrixForm[DAE]
uval = NDSolve[DAE, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, simtime}]
```

but it is not working, giving me an `underdetermined system` error.

Comment: The last line of code should be `uval = NDSolve[DAE, var, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, simtime}]`, but this reveals a more fundamental problem, mixing ODEs and PDEs.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the mistake.  But this does NOT solve the problem as @bbgodfrey pointed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the help of [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

We first eliminate `Ib0` and `Ib1` from the code because DAE system is troublesome compared to ODE system for `NDSolve`. It's better to avoid introducing them from the very beginning to make the code cleaner, but here I'll just modify your `DAE` for simplicity:

```
newdae = DeleteCases[
  DAE /. Rule @@@ (DAE[[7 ;; 8]] /. (a_ == b_) :> (Head@a == (Function[t, #] &@b))), 
  True | Is[__Integer] == _]
```

Then we extract those equations involving `Is` and `Vs`:

```
{eq@1, eq@2} = GatherBy[newdae, FreeQ[#, Is | Vs[__]] &]
```

Finally, discretize those involving `Is` and `Vs` and solve the resulting system:

```
domain = {0, 1}; points = 25; difforder = 2;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{Is, Vs}[t, x], t, grid, difforder];
delete = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
eqlst = MapAt[delete, ptoofunc@eq@1, {1}]

uval = NDSolveValue[{eqlst, eq@2}, {Is /@ grid, Vs /@ grid, Head /@ var[[5 ;;]]}, {t, 0, 
   simtime}]
```

`Is` and `Vs` is discretized in $x$ direction in `uval`. If you prefer a continuous version, we can:

```
sol@Is = rebuild[uval[[1]], grid]

sol@Vs = rebuild[uval[[2]], grid]

Plot3D[sol[Vs][t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a Lot! Awesome. I still don't understand everything. I am trying to understand the code.  I quick question: How do I plot the boundary variables (`Eb0[t], Vb1[t] ')

Comment: in the line " eqlst = MapAt[delete, ptoofunc@eq@1, {1}]", Why are we removing the first and last lines?

Comment: I realized how to plot the boundary variables.

Comment: @kosa It's because `ptoofunc` generates discretized equation on every grid points i.e. $x=0,\frac{1}{24},\frac{2}{24},…, \frac{23}{24}, 1$, but we already have `eq[1][[3 ;; 4]]` at $x=0$ and $x=1$, so we need to _make room_ for them.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I will ptoofunc, to understand the spatial discretization.